# After logging into the iOS app, the feed is blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ios-app-feed

In the last couple of versions of the iOS app (0.1.47-50), the feed loads fine when I'm not logged in. As soon as I log in using my Stack Exchange ID, however,the feed just shows a white, blank screen with the title bar at the top. All other areas of the app are fine (Questions & answers, search, sidebar etc).

I've tried reinstalling the app over the top of the existing app, logging out and logging back in again, and completely deleting the app and reinstalling. Unfortunately the app still exhibits the same behaviour.

Has anybody else seen this?

Comment: We're investigating.

Answer (score 1):

I think I more-or-less know what happened to put you in this bad state.  Some of it is guesswork, but I think what happened is your very first attempt to get feed items failed for some reason, and the app didn't cache any items (either it never received them, or it crashed in the middle of handling it, or something along those lines).  Later, when you tried to refresh, the feed didn't produce any new items for you.  When you refresh the feed, you are only requesting since the last time, so your local cache remained empty.

I've got a fix I'm testing in my dev environment that will get you your initial feed items, but I'm still investigating reasons why the feed is *still* not giving you new items and I don't want to deploy the fix until we understand that part, so your feed is going to be hosed a while longer (sorry!).

If any of this doesn't sound right to you for some reason, please let me know.  I'll post updates as we discover more.

**Update**: I think part of this is just that new accounts don't have much feed history to pull up.  I'll push my fix, and then I think you should be back to normal.  Post back to meta again if you have any more problem.

Comment: Thanks Ben. That all sounds exactly like what I was seeing. As of build 0.1.54, though, it all seems fixed. I can now see the feed even when logged on. Thanks for the swift fix.